# Nested routing - the new action only fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Here is my routes file:

```
  resources :locations do
    resources :comments
  end
```

and the controllers:

```
    class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base

      def index
        @commentable = find_commentable
        @comments = @commentable.comments.where(:company_id => session[:company_id])
      end

      def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comment }
    end
  end

      def new

        @comment = Comment.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @comment }
        end
      end

      def create
        @commentable = find_commentable
        @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
        @comment.user_id = session[:user_id]
        @comment.company_id = session[:company_id]
        if @comment.save
          flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
          redirect_to :id => nil
        else
          render :action => 'new'
        end
      end

      private

      def find_commentable
        params.each do |name, value|
          if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
            return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
          end
        end
        nil
      end

    end
```

and `rake routes`:

> ```
>     location_comments GET        /locations/:location_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
>                        POST       /locations/:location_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
>   new_location_comment GET        /locations/:location_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
>  edit_location_comment GET        /locations/:location_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
>       location_comment GET        /locations/:location_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
>                        PUT        /locations/:location_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
>                        DELETE     /locations/:location_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
>              locations GET        /locations(.:format)                                locations#index
>                        POST       /locations(.:format)                                locations#create
>           new_location GET        /locations/new(.:format)                            locations#new
>          edit_location GET        /locations/:id/edit(.:format)                       locations#edit
>               location GET        /locations/:id(.:format)                            locations#show
>                        PUT        /locations/:id(.:format)                            locations#update
>                        DELETE     /locations/:id(.:format)                            locations#destroy
> ```

It's a bit ugly (more details here: [Polymorphic Comments with Ancestry Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369896/polymorphic-comments-with-ancestry-problems)) given that the location <=> comment association is polymorphic.

`/locations/1/comments/` loads as does `/locations/1/comments/1` but `/locations/1/comments/new` throws a routing error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"locations"}`.

My logs are showing:

```
Started GET "/locations/100041506421W500/comments/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-29 00:37:43 -0600
Processing by CommentsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"location_id"=>"100041506421W500"}
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered comments/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"locations"}):
  app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments__form_html_erb__3729217817518084843_70306885927480'
  app/views/comments/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_comments_new_html_erb___4071030466810932409_70306918426640'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:19:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms)
```

It looks like its rendering the form and then somewhere the 500 error crops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in the `new` view you've got a broken link to `location_path`, which translates to {controller: 'location', action: 'show'}, which is an invalid route (it needs a location ID).

Comment: Yup... never would have figured that out in a million years.  Just need to figure our the polymorphic_path to replace it with.